# .where created_at time match another created_at - format .where(created_at)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to query the database with a .where created_at equals another created_at.

```
object_2 = Model.where(created_at: object_1.created_at)

The Model's created_at = "2014-10-15 13:31:58.654969"
object_1's created_at = "2014-10-15 13:31:58.444636"
```

The problem is that the milliseconds are different. How do I only match on the DateTime? 2014-10-15 13:31:58

**"Solution"**

I ended up going for a range just to be safe

```
Model.where(created_at: object_1.created_at - 1.minute..object_1.created_at + 1.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wanted to truncate the milliseconds, you could do something like this:

```
object_2 = Model.where(created_at: object_1.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: This truncates the milliseconds on the object_1. but still mismatches on the Model.created_at. 

2014-10-15 13:31:58.444636 != 2014-10-15 13:31:58